# How to change span text color to blue or red based on span value with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have multiple  with various numerical values, example:

```
<span class="getPtsValue">20</span>
<span class="getPtsValue">0</span>
<span class="getPtsValue">225</span>
<span class="getPtsValue">100</span>
<span class="getPtsValue">0</span>
<span class="getPtsValue">60</span>
```

I want to color all spans that have a "0" red and all spans that have a number higher than 100, blue.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var getPtsValue = $('.getPtsValue').html(); // = 1
    if (getPtsValue == 0){
        $('.getPtsValue').addClass("text-red");
    }
    if (getPtsValue > '100'){
        $('.getPtsValue').addClass("text-blue");
    }
});
```

Problem is, my code changes ALL spans that have a class of "getPtsValue" to blue. How do I apply the color change to ONLY those spans with a value of 0 to red and spans with a value of 100 or greater to blue?

Comment: Can i ask you why for 0 you check for actually a number, but for > 100 you check against a string? Also, you may want to use jQuery's .each()

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This needs a Loop to examine the value for each element. You currently have it getting HTML on all the elements, so results will vary.

Answer (score 1):

On DOM Ready get the spans, iterate them and convert text to `int` with `parseInt`, if the value is not `NaN` and meets the condition, add the className appropriate for the color

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.getPtsValue').each(function() {
        const val = parseInt($(this).text());
        if(!isNaN(val) && val === 0){
           $(this).addClass("text-red");
        } else if(!isNaN(val) && val >= 100) {
           $(this).addClass("text-blue");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.text-red {
  color:red;
}
.text-blue {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="getPtsValue">20</span>
<span class="getPtsValue">0</span>
<span class="getPtsValue">225</span>
<span class="getPtsValue">100</span>
<span class="getPtsValue">0</span>
<span class="getPtsValue">60</span>
```

Comment: It works! Dude you rock.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".getPtsValue").each(function(i, el) {
    var point = parseInt($(el).text().trim());
    if (point == 0) {
      $(el).addClass("red");
    } else if (point > 100) {
      $(el).addClass("blue");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="getPtsValue">20</span>
<span class="getPtsValue">0</span>
<span class="getPtsValue">225</span>
<span class="getPtsValue">100</span>
<span class="getPtsValue">0</span>
<span class="getPtsValue">60</span>
```

This makes use of `.each()` which will iterate each element.

https://api.jquery.com/each/

> **Description:** Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.

To ensure that we compare a Number to a Number. When we get `.html()` or `.text()`, it will be a String. We can use `parseInt()` to cast it as an Integer.

We then use `.addClass()` to add a Class name to the element. This can be any value you want, I just used `red` and `blue`.

Comment: @RyanWilson update

Comment: this is making anything between 0 to 100 blue, what he did not asked for point > 100 should be enough on the "blue" condition
Edit: i see you changed again now ^^

Comment: So many great answers, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $("span.getPtsValue").each((index, elem) => {
    $(elem)
      .removeClass()
      .addClass(+$(elem).text() === 0 ? 'text-red' : 'text-blue');
  });
});
```

```css
.text-red {
  color: red;
}

.text-blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="getPtsValue">20</span>
<span class="getPtsValue">0</span>
<span class="getPtsValue">225</span>
<span class="getPtsValue">100</span>
<span class="getPtsValue">0</span>
<span class="getPtsValue">60</span>
```